# NavigationBarStyle issue when switching from iOS 4 to 5

Tags: iphone, ios, coding-style, navigationbar

Have a little design issue after having upgraded to iOS 5 and Xcode 4.2

This is how my view looked in iOS 4:

[1 http://casperslynge.dk/1](http://casperslynge.dk/1)

And this is how it looks like in iOS 5:

[2 http://casperslynge.dk/2](http://casperslynge.dk/2)

In my navigation delegate I have the following method to draw the "image" at the top:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image;
    if(self.barStyle == UIBarStyleDefault){
        image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"topbar_base.png"];
    }
    else{
        image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"nyhedsbar_base.png"];    
    }
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(-1, -1, self.frame.size.width+3, self.frame.size.height+3)];
}
```

And inside my controller I set the following:

```
self.navigationBarStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

How come it is not working in iOS 5?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use subclassing or categories for the custom drawing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under iOS5, you need to use `UIAppearance`. Have a look at that. Here's an example for using it conditionally so that you can continue to support iOS4:

```
// iOS5-only to customize the nav bar appearance
if ([[UINavigationBar class] respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)]) {
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"NavBarBackground.png"];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:img forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

As you can see, this sets a custom background image for *all* UINavigationBars. There are lots of things you can do with UIAppearance. You'll want to keep any custom stuff you're currently doing in `drawRect:` since pre-iOS4 devices will still use that and not the new UIAppearance code.

Comment: If you use subclassing (and not categories, which I suspect Casper Slynge might be doing) you can use the same code for both iOS5 and everything below.

Comment: In my particular case, the code above was added when we tested for iOS5 compatibility. We had drawRect: defined in a category to do a similar thing as the OP is doing. We kept the drawRect code, for pre-iOS5 devices; it's not called under iOS5, apparently. Plus, the UIAppearance code above had to be called MUCH earlier (in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) than the drawRect code gets called by the system to have any effect.

Comment: So the above code will apply for every navigationbar. What if I want to switch between two different images?

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I am saying :) According to Apple's docs, overriding methods in categories is and has been simply wrong (no offense) but its done so in many tutorials.

Comment: @CasperSlynge I think you can achieve that with a slightly different use of UIAppearance in this case. I believe you can specify appearance characteristics for classes that appear within other classes or perhaps even for objects of a given class. Honestly, I solved my issue and moved on to the next issue without digging in-depth into UIAppearance. (Doing so is on my to-do list, of course!)

Comment: I figured it out myself. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Phlibbo Yeah, but it works. :-) And it's a common "quick" way to achieve certain kinds of modifications without having to subclass. Sometimes subclassing is overkill when all you want to do is execute an extra line of code. :-) I'm not arguing with you, of course. I'm all for doing things by the book whenever possible.

Comment: Solved the issue the following way. Threw your code into my original drawRect method. By setting the UIBarStyle to either default or something else I can switch between images. Thanks

Comment: Still one issue though. Can you see the small bar/banner beneath the navigationBar? That is still there?

Comment: Issue with a frame.origin perhaps? Just a guess.